# Cpp error: 'size' is not a member of 'std' although -std=c++1z in compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, size, std

I recently moved my compiler to C++17, and have been able to use the new functionality like std::array just fine but I am getting an error while trying to use std::size(array). Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the test file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};

    int j = std::size(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
            std::cout << arr.at(i);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

and here is the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Tests (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -std=c++1z  -c C:\Dev\Tests\Main.cpp -o obj\Debug\Main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Tests.exe obj\Debug\Main.o   
C:\Dev\Tests\Main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Dev\Tests\Main.cpp:9:13: error: 'size' is not a member of 'std'
     int j = std::size(arr);
             ^
```

I've tried checking for other compiler errors but I can't see it.

Comment: Have you tried the `-std=c++17` flag instead?

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks for the idea. Yes, just now. Same error and I confirmed the build log showed the changed flag.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? It appears from [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017) that non-member size , etc were added for gcc 6.1

Comment: @MarshallClow I went to the CodeBlocks\bin folder and checked for gcc --version. It says gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0

Comment: @MarshallClow So that might explain it.

Comment: Your compiler might support C++17 partially, which means it supports some features but not all.

Comment: @Jassaway Consider closing the question if gcc version was the reason

Comment: This page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support helps me a lot with such problems.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I downloaded an updated GCC and updated my IDE compiler and debug settings and it solved this problem... and gave me another problem with the debugger :) Since it is a different problem I'll have to post another question.